# How to recover the SQLite database directory?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using android SQLite for the first time and i created a class "MyDatabaseOpenHelper"  by extending "SQLiteOpenHelper" class as
below

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";
    private static final String MY_TABLE = "MY_TABLE";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String HEADING = "Heading";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    private static final String TYPE = "Type";
    private static final String TIME = "Time";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MY_TABLE + " ( " + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + HEADING + " VARCHAR, " + DESCRIPTION + " VARCHAR, " + TYPE + " INTEGER, " + TIME +" VARCHAR);";


    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.d("SQLException", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Everything runs successfully, and when i checked in the package
"data/data/my-package" in the Device File Explorer i observed the newly created database. But mistakenly i deleted that database directory from the package.When i am running my app again, i cannot see the database directory in the "data/data/my-package" in the Device File Explorer.
How can i recover it?

Comment: How are you invoking this sqlite helper? The database gets created on a call to `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`. You might also want to remove the exception swallowing in `onCreate()`, even if that is not the problem here.

Comment: Uninstall the app and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have backed up the folder and any files in the folder or sub-folders then you can't restore the folder. However, running the App would likely rebuild the folder (assuming a typical use of SQLite).

If you don't see it and could before then it may be that you haven't re-selected the device as the list doesn't get refreshed by the ***Device File Explorer*** rather it appears to be a cached list (deleting, however, is reflected in the cached list).